# "git push" gets stuck on "Total"

Tags: git, terminal, repository

I have a problem with uploading to my GitHub repository using Terminal on Macbook.

When I `git push -u origin main` it gets stuck on `Total 339 (delta 103), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0` and there doesn't seem to be a progress bar or anything to indicate anything more is happening.

I needed to reduce some of the file sizes as they were too big previously, but it's still happening.

Does anyone have any recommendations of what to do?

Comment: I'm getting the same issue for many small files. Possible that something is wrong with GitHub.

Comment: The issue might be the version of git. I'm curious what `git --version` returns for you. It's `2.40.1` for me, which perhaps has an issue. You likely have another version of git installed at `/usr/bin/git` that might not have this issue. This fixed the issue for me (using `/usr/bin/git push` instead of simply `git push`).

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to a [bug](https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/11157) in curl 8.1.0 which is used by git. Downgrading to an older version of curl resolves the issue.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for getting back to me! I have version git version 2.34.1. Gonna try updating git now and see if that fixes things - fingers crossed!

Comment: sadly the git update didn't fix the problem, still stuck on total. Do you perhaps have any other suggestions?

Comment: I updated my answer, the problem (in my case at least) was actually due to curl (version can be checked via `curl --version`) being too new. If that's not the issue, try running `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 GIT_TRACE=1 git push -u origin main`. This will print some more information. Paste the lines after `Total 339...` here, maybe we can figure out why it's stalling.

Comment: hi there! did u find any answer for this, I've been stuck for days... thanks in advance

Comment: @Fada The answer is to upgrade to curl 8.1.2 or greater. The current latest version is 8.6.0.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i solved the problem by undoing the last commit using

```
git reset HEAD~
```

Then I try add+commit_push modified folders separately. In the process I've found that I have .DS_store file currently untracked, so I naturally add it to the .gitignore. Everything went fine after that.

p.s: I dont know if the .DS_store is the real culprit or not. It just everything worked after individual folder add/commit/push and adding that file to the ignore list